# filters doesn't apply for large images in fabric 2.4.6

Tags: fabricjs

> FabricJS Can't Apply Filters To Large Image Due To “Max Texture Size”
>       I'm trying to apply filters to an image of size(5168X3448). Could some help me out to solve this problem?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="color">Apply color</button>
  <canvas id="c" width=500 height=500></canvas>
</body>
</html>
<script>
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  fabric.Image.fromURL('driver.png', function (img) {
    img.set({
      scaleX: 0.1,
      scaleY: 0.1,

    })
    canvas.add(img);

    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
      color: 'red',
      mode: 'multiply'
    });
    img.filters.push(filter);
    img.applyFilters();
    canvas.renderAll();
  }, {
      crossOrigin: 'null'
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a higher max texture size for your canvas like this: `fabric.textureSize = 5168`.

Be aware though that you may run into issues with hardware support when using such a large value. Official Fabric.js documentation states that a `textureSize` of 4096 is a fairly safe limit, so ideally you'll want to try to keep your images below that to avoid hardware issues.

Recommended reading: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-filters